# fancybox-2 horizontal scrollbar off

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

fancybox version 2 is showing `#fancybox-inner` horizontal scrolling bar by any reason. Even I changed the size of the box it is showing scrolling bar. How can I hide horizontal scrolling bar?

```
function display_dialog() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: '/ContactSubmission/',
            type: 'ajax',
            padding: 15,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'normal',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            closeSpeed: 'slow',
            autoSize: true,
            scrolling: 'auto',
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'float'
                },
                overlay: {
                    locked: true
                }
            },
            afterLoad: function(){ 
              $("#fancybox-frame").css({'overflow-x':'hidden'}); 

            } 
        });

    };
```

I tried `$("#fancybox-frame").css({'overflow-x':'hidden'});` still not working.

Comment: You have `scrolling: 'auto' ` when you open the box.  Did you try setting it to `scrolling: 'hidden' `? I'm not familiar with fancybox, but if it adds this as an in-line style, it would override your afterLoad css.  You could also try adding '!important' in the afterLoad css, as a last resort.

Comment: You set `scrolling: 'auto'` but I guess it should be `scrolling: 'no'`

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't even edit the js to do this, I would edit the CSS.

Try

```
#fancybox-inner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

(though I thought fancybox-inner is normally a class, not an ID, so if that doesnt work try .fancybox-inner instead)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    [...],
    scrolling: 'auto',
    afterLoad: function() { 
        this.wrap.find('.fancybox-inner').css({
            'overflow-y': 'auto',
            'overflow-x': 'hidden'
        });
    } 
});
```

You have to set the css-property `overflow` on the `.fancybox-inner`-element and on `afterLoad` because `beforeLoad` the settings from fancybox-property `scrolling` will be set an can override your's.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it will occur due to dimension of fancy box. 
For example,

```
$.fancybox({
   href: '#reviseDiv',
   width: 800    //the width of fancy box is 800 pixel 
   });



 <div class="widget-content" style="display: none;width:800px;margin-left:30%;">
    <div id="reviseDiv" style="width:750px;margin-left:5%"> 
           //here width not exceed from width of fancy box

 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: yah! exactly this is my problem. Thanks save my time